Local modules and small submodules
Recall that a right $R$-module $M$ ($R$ is a ring with unity) is called local if it has a unique maximal submodule. A submodule $N$ of $M$ is called small if, whenever $M=N+N_1$ then $M=N_1$. I need to prove (or disprove) that if $M$ is a local module then every proper submodule of $M$ is small. I think the argument of the proof is easy but, unfortunately, I don't see it. May anyone please give me a hint?.
A second question: Is it true that a local module is cyclic?.

Why all proper submodules are small in this case? @rschwieb

Consider the right $\mathbb{Z}$-module $M=\mathbb{Q} \oplus \mathbb{Z}_p$, where $p$ is a positive prime number. Clearly, the submodules $\mathbb{Q} \oplus 0$ and $0 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_p$ are not small submodules of $M$. We show that $M$ is a local module.
Observe that $M/(\mathbb{Q} \oplus 0) \cong \mathbb{Z}_p$ is a simple module. Hence, $\mathbb{Q} \oplus 0$ is a maximal submodule of $M$. We claim that $\mathbb{Q} \oplus 0$ is the unique maximal submodule. To see this, let $K \subset M$ be any maximal submodule of $M_\mathbb{Z}$. Assume on the contrary that $K \neq \mathbb{Q} \oplus 0$. Thus, $\mathbb{Q} \oplus 0 \subsetneqq K + (\mathbb{Q} \oplus 0)$ (otherwise, $K \subset \mathbb{Q} \oplus 0 \subset M$ and hence, by the maximality of $K$, we get $K= \mathbb{Q} \oplus 0$, contradicting the assumption $K \neq \mathbb{Q} \oplus 0$). Since $\mathbb{Q} \oplus 0 \subset K + (\mathbb{Q} \oplus 0) \subset M$, we get $M=K+ (\mathbb{Q} \oplus 0)$ (as $\mathbb{Q} \oplus 0$ is a maximal submodule of $M$ and $\mathbb{Q} \oplus 0 \neq K + (\mathbb{Q} \oplus 0)$). Now, $M/K = [K+(\mathbb{Q} \oplus 0)]/ K  \cong (\mathbb{Q} \oplus 0) / [K \cap (\mathbb{Q} \oplus 0)]$ is a simple module. Therefore, $K \cap (\mathbb{Q} \oplus 0)$ is a maximal submodule of $\mathbb{Q} \oplus 0$. But, as $(\mathbb{Q} \oplus 0)_\mathbb{Z} \cong \mathbb{Q}_\mathbb{Z}$, we deduce that $\mathbb{Q}_\mathbb{Z}$ has a maximal submodule which is impossible ($\mathbb{Q}_\mathbb{Z}$ does not contain any maximal submodules). Consequently, $\mathbb{Q} \oplus 0$ is the unique maximal submodule of $M_\mathbb{Z}$.

Kindly take a look at this argument. We do not need Goursat's Lemma here.  @Lukas Heger

Assume that $M$ is local with maximal submodule $U$. Further assume that $M$ is finitely generated. This implies that every proper submodule is contained in a maximal submodule. Since that is unique, all proper submodules are contained in $U$. Therefore, we cannot have $M = N + N'$ with proper submodules $N,N'$. So every proper submodule is small.
If $M$ is not finitely generated, I think it doesn't have to be true.

The statement is indeed true if $M$ is finitely generated. I know that. I ask for the case when $M$ is not finitely generated. Anyway, I appreciate your help.

In the finitely generated case, it's also easy to see that $M$ must be cyclic: take any $m \in M \setminus U$, then $\langle m\rangle$ is not contained in any maximal submodule and hence $\langle m\rangle =M$

Unless I'm mistaken, the following is a counterexample. Take $R=\Bbb Z$ and let $p$ be a prime number. Let $M=\Bbb Z[1/p]/\Bbb Z \oplus \Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z$ (the first summand is the (in)famous Prüfer $p$-group.) I claim that $\Bbb Z[1/p]/\Bbb Z \oplus \{0\}$ is the unique maximal submodule of $M$. It's clear that it is maximal, as the quotient is simple. Let $U$ be any maximal submodule.
I claim that $\pi_1(U)$ is infinite, where $\pi_1$ is the projection onto the first factor. If $\pi_1(U)$ is finite, then $U$ is finite, as the second summand is finite. But then $M/U$ is an infinite simple abelian $p$-group which does not exist. Thus we have proven the infinitude of $\pi_1(U)$.
Thus $\pi_1(U)=\Bbb Z[1/p]/\Bbb Z$, because every proper subgroup of the Prüfer $p$-group is finite.
As $\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z$ is simple, there are two possibilities for $\pi_2(U)$: $\pi_2(U)=\{0\}$ and $\pi_2(U)=\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z$. In the second case, we can use Goursat's lemma and the fact that $\Bbb Z[1/p]/\Bbb Z$ doesn't have any nonzero finite quotient to see that $U=M$, which is a contradiction. The first case directly implies $U=\Bbb Z[1/p]/\Bbb Z \oplus \{0\}$, which is what we want.
Having established that $M$ is local, we can see that not every subgroup of $M$ is contained in $U$ and thus for any such subgroup $N$ that is not contained in $U$ (e.g. the subgroup $\{0\} \oplus \Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z$), we have $U+N=M$, so not every submodule of $M$ is small.
